# Oracle updating table based on a join

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables

```
table 1 : rm_example(customer, weekno, salenum, card_type,...., imputed)
table 2 : rm_dummy(customer, weekno, imputed)
```

The imputed column in table one is null(all columns).

I want to set "imputed" column in table 1 with the value of "imputed" in table two where customer and weekno match....

below the query I wrote.....but it is taking forever to execute...

```
update rm_example e 
set e.imputed = 
      (select imputed  
       from rm_dummy d 
       inner join rm_example e on e.customer=d.customer and e.weekno=d.weekno)...
```

Is something wrong with the query?

I am working on remote database using sqldeveloperplus...and we are talking about million rows.

Comment: Oracle SQL performance problems generally require an execution plan, which would also save you from having to include other essential details such as how many rows there are in each table.

Answer (score 1):

MERGE is usually quite a bit faster than an UPDATE with a subquery (the syntax might seem a little bit weird, but you'll get used to it); this assumes rm_example has a primary key column PK:

```
MERGE INTO rm_example target
USING 
  (SELECT e.pk as e_pk,
          d.imputed  
   FROM rm_dummy d 
   INNER JOIN rm_example e ON e.customer=d.customer AND e.weekno=d.weekno) src
ON (target.pk = src.e_pk)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET target.imputed = src.imputed;
```

Comment: Well it can be faster, but an update based on an inline view ought to at least match the performance.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP wasn't using that (he was using a subquery only to fetch the new value, which IME is almost always much slower than MERGE).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be faster than what you have done already but you try this

```
UPDATE
  (SELECT e.imputed, d.imputed
   FROM rm_example e 
   INNER JOIN rm_dummy d ON e.customer = d.customer AND e.weekno = d.weekno)
SET e.imputed = d.imputed;
```

After reading [8 Bulk Update Methods Compared (Oracle)](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450) I see this is really a Deprecated method that a `MERGE` syntax should be used. But in saying that depending on your system this could possibly have better performance

Comment: I don't think that "deprecated" is the right word here, as it implies some official statement from Oracle. There should be nothing wrong with the performance of this statement even compared with a merge, and in fact it can be more compact and intuitive particularly where only a subset of rows is to be updated.